# Cannot set default file associations for .xml files

Tags: finder, ms-office, file, textedit

I'm on MacOS Ventura. I use it for work so MS Office is installed.

No matter what I do, XML files seem to always want to open with MS Word. I want them to open with another app. I'm using TextEdit as an example here:

I've done the standard `Right click > Open with > Choose TextEdit > "Always open with"` method.

This opens the file with TextEdit this one time, but system-wide XML's remain associated to MS Word.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting it from File > Get Info in the Finder?

Comment: This seemed to work, but the icon for each file in Finder is still the MS word icon, not the TextEdit icon. However it does properly open with the desired app now, thank you.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using a "proper" ;-) text editor, like BBEdit, which will do things like syntax colouring and provide other tools to help navigating through and working with XML syntax. (and other languages/codes).

Comment: "proper" ? I literally put " I'm using TextEdit as an example here" in the original question.

Comment: Ah: Sorry, I missed that bit. Though it always helps to give the actual details of the apps you are using, in case that's relevant to the problem.